# Exporting images from #+RESULTS in org code blocks does not work

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, literate-programming

When exporting images to multiple formats (I have tried html and pdf), the export works but the image is not displayed. This is only a problem when the image is in a #+RESULTS: block. Moving the image outside the results block fixes the problem. For example:

```
#+begin_src jupyter-python :results file :file ~/image.jpg
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

    plt.plot(a, b)
    plt.show()
#+end_src
#+RESULTS:
:RESULTS:
#+attr_org: :width 547
[[file:~/image.jpg]]
:END:
```

will not display an image.

The problem occurs when using pandoc or org-export.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your source block has successfully produced the image file[1], there are two problems: you need to add an `:exports results` header to your code block so that the results *can* be exported and you need to make sure that drawers can be exported (they are not by default I believe[3]). So the following *should* work[2]:

```org
# enable exports of drawers
#+OPTIONS: d:t

* Foo
#+begin_src jupyter-python :exports results :results file :file ~/image.jpg
...
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
:RESULTS:
#+attr_org: :width 547
[[file:~/image.jpg]]
:END:
```

See the Org manual for more details: [Export settings](https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-Settings.html) for the `#+OPTIONS` setting and [Exporting code blocks](https://orgmode.org/manual/Exporting-Code-Blocks.html) for the `:exports` header (note the `s` BTW - spelling it `:export` is a common mistake).

BTW, it's not clear *why* your result is in a drawer: presumably you have a `:results drawer` header either on your code block or as a property, but you have not shown that in your question. If that is the case, you can get rid of that header instead of enabling drawer export with the `#+OPTION` above.

---

Footnotes:

[1] The code block seems incomplete to me - e.g. don't you need a `savefig` somewhere? - but I don't have a `jupyter-python` evaluator so I can't test that.

[2] It works for me: I had to use my own code block and image, but that should not make any difference.

[3] I was wondering why the OP's answer of `:exports both` would work for him, so I looked a bit more closely and found out I was wrong: the default value of `org-export-with-drawers` is `(not "LOGBOOK")` - IOW, all drawers except the `LOGBOOK` drawer *are* exported. So the `d:t` option is *not* needed; only `:exports results` on the code block is needed for the results to be exported (`:exports both` exports both the code *and* the results).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add

```
:exports both
```

to the header.